# What are the difficulties in importing features of Android, like Unity3D Player, to Linux in general?

Tags: linux, android, unity

We know that Android is an open source Linux-based distro. And we know some features developed for Android are required for the Linux community for many years, and are denied (like Unity3D Player).

What are the difficulties in importing Android features to other Linux distributions, like Ubuntu, Fedora and others?

Comment: No, I don't have specific things in mind. And Gille's answer clarify what I want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty is that it's a completely different operating system. Android is not a Linux distribution. The only thing that's common between Android and [GNU/X11/Apache/Linux/TeX/Perl/Python/FreeCiv](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-linux-faq.html#many) (usually known as “Linux” or “Linux distributions”) is the Linux [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29). Linux is based on [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-based APIs, the [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) for the graphical interface, and many libraries that build upon these foundations, using core concepts such as processes, files, pipes and windows. Android is based on its own [Java APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) with [specific concepts](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html), using core concepts such as activities, services, binders and intents. Porting something like Unity3D to Linux would be as much work as other ports such as OSX (which has more POSIX bits than Android, but also has a GUI that's completely different from Unix/Linux's X11) and Android.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very very much! :D