# Why is compatibility with Android not a common feature in Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, android

Since Android is based on Linux (and I understand is only a Java layer on top of Linux), I wonder why Linux does not generally run Android applications.

Why is an Android compatibility layer, either with its own desktop or within X, not a standard feature of modern Linux distributions?

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30236/88378) (from the `Related` list over there ->) for some reasons.

Comment: For the opposite thing, check out Maru OS or Complete Linux Installer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android is based on the Linux **kernel**. That, and a very stripped-down [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/). All the rest of [GNU/X11/Apache/Linux/TeX/Perl/Python/FreeCiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy) is not present on Android. Asking why Linux doesn't emulate Android is like asking why trucks don't emulate airplanes — after all they're both big vehicles with wheels at the bottom.

Most Android applications are specifically designed to handle the limitations of a portable device: limited computing resources, energy consumption paramount, small screen, no external input device. There are usually similar applications for PC-style computers, except for location-related applications which are generally not useful outside of a mobile device.

You can run Android applications in the [emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) provided by Google. This is a developer tool, because the main application of running Android applications on a PC-style computer is to test them.

There *is* some work on systems that combine Linux with Android (such as [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android), but it's been abandoned), mainly running on intermediate-format devices (tablets), but also on smaller devices (phones) to allow users of mobile devices to run existing applications from the larger-format world. Since the two operating systems have mostly compatible kernels, it's possible to run the rest of the operating system side by side (that's easier than rewriting the Android libraries to work on top of Linux/X11 or vice versa). There are significant technical difficulties, however. Probably the biggest one is that the GUI operate on completely different software: Linux uses [the X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) like other unix variants while Android has [its own stack](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html).

Comment: That's a correct technical explanation of the differences between the systems but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm I thought it did. Why is compatibility not a common feature? Because it's a huge amount of work and not extremely useful.

Comment: Might be the best answer I can get. I still think an Android desktop running on alt-F8 would be great to play games and worth the effort. Hence I was wondering why there was no demand for it.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm If you want to play games that aren't too CPU-intensive, run them in the emulator.

Comment: Interestingly, Maru OS seems to have achieved this, but just the other way around.

Comment: @Fiksdal Which way is “the other way”? I'm not familiar with Maru OS, but my impression is that it's Debian on top of Android, which is the easy way (if you only want the command line, it isn't very difficult, I've done that myself: run `debootstrap --foreign` on a Linux machine, copy the resulting directory tree to the Android machine, and run `debootstrap --second-stage`).

Comment: @Gilles Sure, didn't mean to imply that it was equally easy. But Maru OS is still pretty cool. Android apps seem to be integrated into XFCE, so that you can view them side by side with GNU applications, etc. Looks like even Google are planning to [merge Chrome OS and Android](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3072645/android/android-chrome-os-merger.html), in a way. (Depends on how you define "merge"). I think all that is pretty cool.

Comment: @Gilles My comment was poorly articulated. I should have said: "Maru OS has achieved the opposite thing."

Answer (score 0):

It because the architecture of Android ist different and developed for mobile devices.

[Look at this for more informations.](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.de/2012/06/architecture-of-android-in-order-to.html)